# How do you convert ulaw wave files to PCM in python?

Tags: python, wav

I'm trying to convert a wave file holding 8kHz 8bit mono ulaw data (64kbps) to PCM. I'm looking through the docs and found audioop, ulaw2lin seems to be what I want, but the docs are vague on how to get the proper inputs for the file. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the program :

```
avconv
```

which is a modern fork of ffmpeg, source at https://libav.org

If you wish to roll your own code to parse the WAV file by all means.
Here are some WAV reference docs

```
http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html
http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/wave.htm
http://unusedino.de/ec64/technical/formats/wav.html
http://www.drdobbs.com/database/inside-the-riff-specification/184409308
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/loading-a-wave-file-r709
```

Park a copy of your ulaw file and mention location so we/I can run
our own WAV format parse code against it.  The mcgill site above mentions ulaw

Comment: Sonicspot and stanford are dead links :(  Others are very useful, thank you!